# Is there pyramid package for storing form related information serverside (avoid mirroring hidden fields)?

Tags: python, forms, pyramid

Background: I'm currently creating a project in pyramid. It uses beaker sessions and SQLAlchemy as DB-backend.

Some forms contain information in hidden fields, with the only purpose of supplying it to the view that processes the post, the user never sees them and doesn't need to. An example:

A DB-entity can be edited by the user. Since all data fields of the entity, including the name, can be edited, the ID of the entity is put in a hidden field, so the view can query the object and update it. This approach has some flaws:

1. The ID of my entities is no concern of my users. They should not even be aware of it.
2. Data being resubmitted by the client can be tinkered with. Someone might try to get access to other entities by forging a different id here.
3. In other scenarios there could be more mirrored data than just an id (maybe the return to url? Maybe much more somewhere). Using hidden fields for that would transmit the data to the client and back, needlessly (bandwidth) and makes it necessary to validate it.

Transmitting data over insecure channels (the client) without need is just wrong. The solution is not that complicated: store that information on the server (in session or DB), and make it accessible with a key (form-id?), similar to a session, with a session-id. Put that totally anonymous token into a hidden field. That will be the only hidden field needed in the form. Everything else would be stored on the server and be restored from the view responding to the post-request (well - I would still have my CSRF-token in there, because it's in all my post requests). This would also make it easy, to give forms a timeout, since you can make the form-id expire after some hours or so.

If I recall correctly, drupals does supply like this by default. I would not really expect pyramid itself to have support for this, but would imagine there must be a package doing this, using the pyramid supplied session object, still could not find any. I'm sure I could write something usable myself, but why do so if there might be something awesome out there already?

Anyone knows of such packages?

Comment: found a question concerning the drupal feature I mentiond: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57336/what-is-the-difference-between-hidden-and-value-types-in-form-api

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you want to update a model without using hidden fields on forms.
Here is how to do it
Using [pyramid_simpleform](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_simpleform) and Urldispatch

```
@view_config(route_name="my_route",renderer="myrenderer.mako")
def update(request):
    id = request.matchdict['id']

    #assuming you have an SQLalchemy model called MyModel which you imported
    #your model has a method that gets by id
    toupdate = MyModel.get_by_id(id)
    form = Form(request, schema=MyModelSchema,obj=toupdate)
    if not toupdate:
        #you can flash a message here and redirect wherever you want
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'))
    if 'submit' in request.POST and form.validate():
        form.bind(toupdate)
        DBSession.add(toupdate)
        DBSession.flush()
        #redirect
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'))
    return dict(form=FormRenderer(form))
```

At the view, just draw your form fields without any hidden field using the form object.

```
#configure your route as below
config.add_route('my_route','/myroute/{id}/edit')
```

## UPDATE

to use [webhelpers tool](http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/WebHelpers/modules/html/tools.html#webhelpers.html.tools.js_obfuscate). Follow as bellow(Using Mako template)

```
<%
from webhelpers.html.tools import js_obfuscate
%>

js_obfuscate("<input type='hidden' name='check' value='valid' />")
```

to obfuscate the data in javascript tag

Comment: That's actually not what I wanted to do. `pyramid_simpleform` is useful (and I use it). But you basically moved the `id` from a hidden field to the url, which does not really change anything in regard of my question. I'd want the id to be stored server side, so that the user cannot know it or mess with it (I would of course verify that the sender has write access to the entity on receiving the post, anyway, but that is not the issue here). Editing was just an example. I want to store arbitrary form related data on server side outside reach of the user. Like the linked drupal value feature

Comment: ok. I now understand. You may use [webhelpers tool](http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/WebHelpers/modules/html/tools.html#webhelpers.html.tools.js_obfuscate) in the form field

Comment: hmm, that is still sending the information to the client and back again (although possibly unreadable/changeable, I did not really look into the details, since using JS, it must go through the client). I'm looking for a tool where you have something like a hidden field containing a random ID (like a UUID maybe). The tool should than (after the request) use that ID to read back values that are stored on the server. webhelpers looks like a tool I will be using for other purposes, but it's not doing what I'm looking for in this question.